# CSS transforms - Image disappears when rotated beyond -180degrees

Tags: html, css, 3d, rotation, css-transforms

Firstly, sorry for the question, I just can't work out where I'm going wrong after many hours of trying!

I have three images, and I am trying to flip them -180 degrees using the transform:rotateY declaration.

I have managed to get them to rotate, but once they get past the -180degrees mark they disappear.

I also want the underlying divs, which contain some text, to appear after the image flips round -180 degrees - as if they were on the back of the image if that makes sense.

Here's the codepen link - http://codepen.io/skoster7/pen/KgwXgB

Here's the code

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  perspective: 700px;
}
.photo img {
  transition-style: preserve-3d;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.sideb {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: tomato;
}
sidea:hover {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.sidea,
.sideb {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.sideb {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="photo">
    <img class="sidea" src="http://cdn.history.com/sites/2/2015/04/hith- 
            father-christmas-lights-iStock_000029514386Large.jpg">
    <div class="sideb">Christmas
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="photo">
    <img class="sidea" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/HalloweenPumpkin2.jpg">
    <div class="sideb">Halloween
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="photo">
    <img class="sidea" src="http://motormarks.co.uk/news/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/easter-chicks.jpg">
    <div class="sideb">Easter
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you trying to get  a 'flashcard' effect where it rotates and the text/colors appear?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Kind of like this - http://jsfiddle.net/M783F/5/ - but on hover instead of click and horizontally instead of vertically

Comment: 1. Do you want rotateX or rotateY? 2. What do you want to happen when the image passes the "front"? Do you want it to appear (in mirror) or not?

Comment: Like this - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozgpXa but ideally with a margin either side of the images so they are spaced out

Answer (score 3):

Modified code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozgpXa

You should rotate container of sides in this case `photo`. And also add some values to get position from top and left to be in the same place.

Comment: That's basically it - thank you. Do you know how to make the images appear completely flush, or side by side with one another?

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd like to get. Could you show example or describe it another way?

Comment: Basically, Is it possible to add spacing inbetween the images so they are not so close together?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Just add margin to .photo class (changed codepen already)

Comment: The Codepen looks the same to me, sorry! I mean inbetween each individual image.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something  like the demo below.

**Recommendations:**

You should also try to write semantic HTML for a cleaner code, maintainability, **accessibility**, SEO and many more. And make your transitions a bit faster, something between 300ms - 500ms, don't expect users to wait 2 seconds for each image they want to flip!

---

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/Lcpwumf1/)**

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.flip-card {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 0 1% 0;
  -webkit-perspective: 700px;
  perspective: 700px;
}
.flip-card figure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-out;
  -webkit-perspective: 700;
  perspective: 700;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.flip-card figure img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flip-card figure figcaption {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flip-card:hover figure,
.flip-card.hover figure {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flip-card figure figcaption p {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2em;
  color: white;
}
.flip-card figcaption {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flip-card:nth-of-type(odd) figcaption {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://fillmurray.com/200/200" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text Example</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://fillmurray.com/300/300" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text Example</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text Example</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://fillmurray.com/500/500" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text Example</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://fillmurray.com/600/600" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text Example</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://fillmurray.com/100/100" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text Example</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

To add more spacing between items just change `margin` property in `.flip-card` class.

---

### EDIT:

**How to make it flip only when someone clicks on it?**

For this requirement we can create a small plugin.

It requires an 'active' class which will flip the cards in our CSS.

```
.flip-card.active figure {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

How to use in JS:

```
var flipcards = new FlipCards({
  cardsClass: "flip-card", //default
  activeClass: "active" //default
});
```

```js
(function(window) {

  "use strict";

  function extend(a, b) {
    for (var key in b) {
      if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        a[key] = b[key];
      }
    }
    return a;
  }

  function flipCards(options) {
    this.options = extend({}, this.options);
    extend(this.options, options);
    this._init();
  }

  flipCards.prototype.options = {
    cardsClass: "flip-card",
    activeClass: "active"
  }

  flipCards.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    var cards = document.getElementsByClassName(this.options.cardsClass),
      i = 0,
      len = cards.length,
      self = this;
    if (len === 0) return;
    for (i, len; i < len; i++) {
      cards[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle(self.options.activeClass);
      });
    }
  }

  flipCards.prototype._init = function() {
    this._initEvents();
  }
  window.FlipCards = flipCards;

  // Support for CommonJS Module format and AMD format.
  if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) {
    module.exports.FlipCards = flipcards;
  } else if ((typeof define !== "undefined" && define !== null) && (define.amd !== null)) {
    define("flipcards.js", function() {
      return flipcards;
    });
  }

})(window);

var flipcards = new FlipCards({
  cardsClass: "flip-card", //default
  activeClass: "active" //default
});
```

```css
.flip-card {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 0 1% 0;
  -webkit-perspective: 700px;
  perspective: 700px;
}

.flip-card figure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-out;
  -webkit-perspective: 700;
  perspective: 700;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card figure img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card figure figcaption {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip-card.active figure {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip-card figure figcaption p {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2em;
  color: white;
}

.flip-card figcaption {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.flip-card:nth-of-type(odd) figcaption {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://fillmurray.com/200/200" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text Example</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://fillmurray.com/300/300" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text Example</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text Example</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://fillmurray.com/500/500" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text Example</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://fillmurray.com/600/600" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text Example</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://fillmurray.com/100/100" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text Example</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

## [Live Example](http://codepen.io/rickyruiz/pen/dvLaNO)

Comment: How to make it flip only when some one clicks on it.

Comment: @ShalinPatel I have updated the answer with a small plugin for you to use. If you have any doubts feel free to ask.